# asp.net unobtrusive validation remove on value change

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have custom validator, everything works except error msg is not removed when value is changed.

```
(function ($) {
$.validator.addMethod('lastcategory', function (value, element) {
    alert(value);
    return value != 0;
}, '');

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('lastcategory');

$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
}(jQuery));
```

My field is hidden-field. When i press submit, value is 0 and error is visible. When i change the value via jquery, eq : 7, error message is still there.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not removed because the change in that hidden field's value is not followed by an event used by the plugin, such as `onfocusout`, `onkeyup`, etc.

In your jQuery, right after you change the value of your hidden field, call [the plugin's `.valid()` method to programmatically trigger another validation test](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid), which will then automatically update any outstanding messages.

```
$('#myHiddenFieldID').val(myNewValue); // whatever code is changing the value of the hidden field.
$('#myFormID').valid();
```

Comment: Default validation check when field is changed. For example, if textbox limit is 6, when i write 7 characters, error is visible, when i delete one character, error is not visible. How i can do that with custom validator, but not on total manual way?

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato, I already showed you how to do it above.  How are you changing the value of the hidden field?  What code is doing that?  That's the place... put `$('#myFormID').valid();` after that.

Comment: I can do that manual so easy, but why validation message dont disappear when i change hidden field value.

$('#myhidden').val(5)

why i need to call manually. As you can see on the link you posted, when u click validate, at begining is false and error is visible, but instantly after you type something, error is not visible. That is what i want to do, after i $('#myhidden').val(5), error do disappear without manual work.

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato, again, just like I explained in my answer, the plugin is triggered by specific `"events"` like `onfocusout`, `onkeyup`, etc. When you change your hidden field 'programmatically', no events are triggered... you've bypassed them all. The plugin is not magic; it needs a trigger. The solution is very simple, trigger the validation 'programmatically' by calling `.valid()`... what's the problem?